# How to Fix NoMethodError When Attempting to Log In in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've set up an authentication system in a simple rails app I'm building. User sign up works fine, however, attempting to log in, results in a no method error that I can't seem to fix. My set up is as follows:

Sessions Controller:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def new; end

  def create
    user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
    if user && user.authenticate(password: params[:session][:password])
      log_in user
      redirect_to user
    else
      flash[:danger] = 'Invalid email/password entered'
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    log_out if logged_in?
    redirect_to root_url
  end
end
```

Sessions Helper:

```
module SessionsHelper
  def log_in(user)
    session[:user_id] = user.id
  end

  def remember(user)
    user.remember
    cookies.permanent.signed[:user_id] = user.id
    cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
  end

  def current_user
    if (user_id = session[:user_id])
      @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: user_id)
    elsif (user_id = cookies.signed[:user_id])
      @current_user = User.find_by(id: user_id)

      if user && user.authenticated?(cookies[:remember_token])
        log_in user
        @current_user = user
      end
    end
  end

  def logged_in?
    !current_user.nil?
  end

  def forget(user)
    user.forget
    cookies.delete(:user_id)
    cookies.delete(:remember_token)
  end

  def log_out
    forget(current_user)
    session.delete(:user_id)
    @current_user = nil
  end
end
```

The following is the error:

```
Started POST "/login" for ::1 at 2020-05-17 12:44:17 -0400
Processing by SessionsController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"[AUTH CONTENT]", "first_name"=>"[SAMPLE]", "last_name"=>"[SAMPLE]", "email"=>"one@example.com", "password_digest"=>"[FILTERED]", "commit"=>"Log in"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 2ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 1031)



NoMethodError (undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass):

app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:5:in `create'
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the key `:email` into the hash at the key `:session`, but there's no such parameter in your request. Fix that or change

```
user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
```

into

```
user = User.find_by(email: params[:email].downcase)
```

Also, same for password. And note that you're passing `:password_digest`, not `:password`

Comment: Good spot @ursus. How would I include that parameter in the request?

Comment: it depends. what are you using? we should see some code

Comment: ```
<%= form_with method: "post" do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :first_name, placeholder: "Enter your first name" %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :last_name, placeholder: "Enter your last name" %><br />
  <%= f.email_field :email, placeholder: "Enter your email" %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password_digest, placeholder: "Enter your password" %><br />
  <%= f.submit "Log in" %>
<% end %>
```
This is the simple form that submits the data for logging in.

Comment: try with `scope: :session`

Comment: `form_with scope: :session, method: "post" do |f| `